# Old version not transferring

Tags: email, data-transfer

I installed a new hard drive in my MacBook and when plugging in old hard drive to transfer files & apps/progs over, some apple software such as Mail, iCal and safari have a cross through them stating that it's an old version and can't be transferred. How could a newer OS (mavericks) not accept and transfer older versions across?? How can I fix this? My calendar is now blank with no birthdays and I can't access any emails over a few days old. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you also upgrade OS X when swapping disks? And did you log in to iCloud (or your email provider) again after booting from the new disk?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could copy the application bundle, it wouldn't copy data like emails or calendar events. The data for Mail is stored in ~/Library/Mail/ and ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/. The data for Calendar is stored in ~/Library/Calendars/ and ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iCal/.

If you didn't already try it, try using Migration Assistant to copy the files from the old installation.